# ImportError: cannot import name 'Encoder' from 'pyflink.common'

Tags: pyflink

from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy, Encoder, Types
run above code got below error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'Encoder' from 'pyflink.common'